# Accessing non static constant in static function of swift class

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift2

I am new to swift. I want to use none static member of swift class in a static function following is my code. I cannot access none static member of class in static function. Is there a way to access non static member in swift function?

```
public class Test{
private let testString:String

init(test:String){
     testString = test
}

static func Get(url:String){
 //Here testString is not accessable..
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to access non-static variables in static functions. You can create a static instance of the class (a way a singleton is made) and access its testString variable, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve such a result. as stated by @Alexander you could create a static instance of the class like a singleton and use that. 
Another way you can do is a simple trick like I did recently, you can have a static version of your variable. What I did was listen to the changes that my instance variable would go through using signals. you can do the same with KVO if you haven't overridden the getter for your variable (KVO compatible) or simply set the static variable whenever you change your instance variable although you must do it closure based (Block in OBJC) otherwise it's a whole big circle than never meets.
Whenever your instance variable's value changed you simply apply the same change to your static variable and when needed in static functions, you simply use the static one.

If you're not comfortable with using KVO or react you can also do something else. you can override the getter and setter for your instance variable and set them both to file or UserDefaults and also create a static method and override the getter to read the file with the same key as your instance variable so you don't have to set your static variable every time something changes.